# SQL Server 2008: How to update a field based on another field in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table which contains fields for employees first names and last names.  There is also a field for username.  How would I make the username automatically populate anytime the first and last name fields are updated?

I want the username field in this format: 'CompanyX\FirstName.LastName'

I have looked into triggers, but I don't think a trigger on a table can update itself.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: yes, a trigger can do it. But what's supposed to happen when the username already exists?

Comment: please show some sample data and expected ouput

Comment: In this table there can be more than one instance of the username.  This table is recording accounts assigned to each employee.

Comment: If you have R2 you could maybe use a computed column.

Comment: I have R2.   I have never used a computed column.  How do I utilize that?  Thanks.

Comment: Google 'SQL Server Computed Column' for starters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a trigger on the table like this.

```
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trg_AuditEmployees]    Script Date: 08/04/2016 10:24:04 ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_AuditEmployees] 
ON [dbo].[employees] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

   update dbo.employees 
   set username = company + 'x\' + lastname + '.' + firstname
   where id = select id from inserted

END
```

Comment: Just a note: best way is to join `inserted` with table and UPDATE column.

Comment: Yes your right, I edited the query. My would overwrite all usernames. I pulled the example from an audit table insert, but didn't change to account for an update

Comment: This works great until you get two people with the same name. But that is a logical problem the OP needs to sort out. The code here is fine.

Comment: The example of a  computed column below should produce the same result

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of a computed column. I tested it and it worked fine.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [Company] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [UserName]  AS (((([Company]+'\')+[FirstName])+'.')+[LastName]) PERSISTED
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Alter Table Table_1
ADD [UserName]  AS (((([Company]+'\')+[FirstName])+'.')+[LastName]) PERSISTED
GO

Answer (score 0):

Create computed column username as concatenating of all these attributes